# Will a straight edge with 4 vertices create ngons?

Tags: modeling, geometry

I'm using Maya but figure you guys will know the answer and didn't know where else to ask. I couldn't find an answer to my question by searching:

I've attached a screenshot below. Basically I want to know if the highlighted faces are Ngons. The edges are straight but each face has one edge that has been subdivided but not edited in any other way.

[image]

And another pic this time with the vertices highlighted in yellow

[image]

Comment: To me, it sure look like they are Ngons. However, if the two vertices of the subdivided edge with the 4 vertices is not part of the highlighted face, then no they would not be Ngons.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a Maya question. This will be more suited to http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maya where you can get a Maya-specific response.

Comment: This question also applies to my blender projects, it's just that my example came from the project I currently have open in Maya. Does the software matter if question needs an answer for any software? (please don't banish it to an unused section of stack exchange ^^)

Comment: Well, if I were personally going to answer, I would have mentioned a blender addon which helps detects ngons, but that would be specific to blender and not to Maya.

Comment: it is an ngone since it has more than 4 vertices, it does matter if they are on the same line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically if it has more than 4 verts it is an ngon, even if some of those verts are co-linear. How various mesh engines deal with this under the hood might vary, but that's beyond the scope of this site. In Blender that's an Ngon.