# Does this flat 5 sided face count as a square?

Tags: modeling

Is this a pentagon or does it count as an square for animation purposes?
It technically has 5 angles, but one of them is flat, so practically it should be a square with 4 sides, but I'm not so sure.
It also is flat on the Z-axis.

[image: 4 angles, 5 sides?]

I'd generally leave it like is but I'm trying to up my game. Thank you

Comment: I think you mean quad, not square, it's definitely not square.  But no, it is not a quad, it is a pentagon (n-gon).

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28844/will-a-straight-edge-with-4-vertices-create-ngons/28847#28847

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a pentagon or the more common general term in 3d, a *n-gon*. You probably want to avoid these for anything realtime such as games or animations since they do not deform or smooth well, make adding more detail cumbersome and games are more optimal with triangulated meshes.

As a simple flat object, it's fine if you are done with the model but again as a rule of thumb, try to stick with quads and tris.

To resolve, you can either:

- Use the join tool (select both vertices and press <kbd>J</kbd>).
- Use the knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd>, select a star point and drag to cut, use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm) to create a tri from the extra vertex or create quads by continuing the edge flow downwards.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It counts as a pentagon. I don't think you can change it either. Or you make it 2 squares by using cut (shortcut K in editmode) and just ad a cut from the extra vert to the center of the edge on the other side.